# Exploring relation between time series

Tags: time-series, econometrics

I have the below time series data:

I want to explore the relationship between dependent variable y and the independent variables x1 and x2.  My aim is not forecasting. Just finding the relationship between these variables and making simulations by changing the dependent variables. I know that, y have some other components too, other than x1 and x2. But it is impossible to find these variables for me. So, I have to do my best using these two dependent variables. The data is monthly data. And it can consist of seasonality.

How can I do such an analysis? I don't want an arima model. I mean, I don't want a model which includes dependent variable's lags and error term lags. Which method should I use? Is it enough just to transform these variables into stationarity variables and trying different models to find the best one?

I will be very glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

Data:

period   y        x1          x2

201401   184     2.23        3.03
201402   194     2.22        3.03
201403   200     2.22        3.07
201404   201     2.13        2.94
201405   184     2.10        2.88
201406   204     2.13        2.89
201407   199     2.13        2.89
201408   200     2.17        2.89
201409   197     2.21        2.86
201410   194     2.27        2.87
201411   196     2.24        2.80
201412   191     2.29        2.82
201501   208     2.34        2.73
201502   203     2.46        2.79
201503   212     2.59        2.81
201504   199     2.66        2.86
201505   200     2.66        2.97
201506   193     2.70        3.03
201507   200     2.69        2.97
201508   206     2.86        3.18
201509   219     3.01        3.38
201510   222     2.94        3.31
201511   233     2.88        3.10
201512   242     2.93        3.18
201601   262     3.02        3.28
201602   260     2.94        3.26
201603   254     2.90        3.22
201604   238     2.83        3.21
201605   241     2.94        3.32
201606   242     2.93        3.29
201607   263     2.97        3.28
201608   238     2.96        3.32
201609   247     2.96        3.32
201610   250     3.08        3.40
201611   267     3.27        3.53
201612   262     3.50        3.69
201701   302     3.73        3.97
201702   286     3.68        3.92
201703   275     3.68        3.93
201704   284     3.66        3.92
201705   294     3.57        3.94
201706   288     3.52        3.95
201707   288     3.57        4.10
201708   301     3.52        4.15
201709   300     3.47        4.14
201710   306     3.67        4.32
201711   307     3.89        4.56
201712   322     3.85        4.55
201801   324     3.78        4.60
201802   331     3.78        4.67
201803   310     3.88        4.79
201804   317     4.06        4.99
201805   330     4.41        5.22
201806   360     4.64        5.42
201807   354     4.76        5.56

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took your series ( length =54 ) and used Transfer Function identification to automatically sort out the impact of the two predictor series and to identify possible omitted deterministic structure. There are a few anomalies (5) that were identified. here is the equation[image] .

The Actual vs Cleansed highlights the identified anomalies [image] . The model statistics are here

[image]

The residuals from the model are free of structure suggesting sufficiency.
[image]

The ACF of the residuals is here

[image]

The Actual/Fit and Forecast graph is here:

[image]

with Actual and Forecast here

[image]

of the forecasts for the next 12 periods is here

[image]

For more on multivariate single equation modelling see https://web.archive.org/web/20160216193539/https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/node/75/ and http://www.math.cts.nthu.edu.tw/download.php?filename=569_fe0ff1a2.pdf&dir=publish&title=Ruey+S.+Tsay-Lec1

There is a need for just 1 seasonal pulse a January effect not 11 as had been suggested.

Also good analytics detect any needed differencing ( as in this case ) and correct lag structures while remedying anomalous data points (which now should be investigated !) [image]

see how Excel compares to this ...

[image]

For good reading and learning ...https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=transfer+function+models

Comment: Thanks a lot @IrishStat for the detailed explanation. Do you know any package in R, which I will able to the similar analysis, where can the anomolies and seasonlity will be detected automatically? Thanks a lot again for sharing your time and for the very useful explanation.

Comment: And when, I look at to the actuals and fits graphs, I suspect about one lag. Maybe,would it be better to include one lag month of the dependent variables? Thanks a lot again.

Comment: AUTOBOX which I have helped to develop has an R version with all the required optional automation . Note that in this case the "seasonality" that was detected was simply a seasonal pulse for the month of January . The appropriate lag structures in this case were Y lag1, X1 contemporaneous and X1 lag1 , X2 lag1 and X2 lag2

Comment: I guess AUTOBOX is not a free tool. Is there any other Package that you know that is free?

Comment: None ...that I know of that treats both causal models and Intervention detection

Answer (score 0):

Linear regression, where you take period and turn it into 11 monthly dummies (leave one out as a reference) and so you end up with 13 X's. Super simple, nothing you said makes me think you need a time-series method or something more complex than linear regression at this point. And you can do all of this in Excel (or any other statistical software).

Comment: Don't I have to transform them into stationary variable?

Comment: no. if there's a trend in Y then you may want to add a 14th X with a simple count (can just start at 1).

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your time to my problem. But one last question. I am confused with that: With this way, won't it be a spurious regression?

Comment: And also maybe, the dependent variable give reaction to the ndependent variables with some lags? So don't i have to need to add lag of independent variables to the model?

Comment: a spurious regression is when two things that are truly not related are found to have a statistical association or correlation. eg, ice cream consumption and crime. Eating ice cream doesn't make people commit crime, but both of them are higher in the summer.

Answer (score 0):

I may be blind to something but this seems a basic linear regression model.

If not linear, try taking logarithms and see if that is linear.

And, if you believe there is serial correlation (which looks highly likely), do first differences or first ratios.  In other words, don't regress on y(x), but on y(x) - y(x-1)  or   y(x)/y(x-1).  In any normal regime, that should give you stationarity.