# Using lagged explanatory variables to forecast future value of depended

Tags: time-series, forecasting, predictive-models, lags

Is there a way or method to use older values (lagged) of independent variables with alternative lags to explain current value of dependent variable? For time series specific

Comment: yes, google for "autoregressive distributed lags" or "koyck distributed lags". there's tons of info on these types of models.

Answer (score 0):

[Exploring relation between time series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/362226/exploring-relation-between-time-series/362258#362258) provides an example of Transfer Function Modelling which leads to equations that can be then expressed as PDL or ADL as suggested by @mlofton. A flow diagram for model building is here http://www.autobox.com/pdfs/A.pdf

It is also called an ARIMAX Model or ARMAX Model [transfer function-noise modelling in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/401681/transfer-function-noise-modelling-in-r/401691#401691).

For a larger set of references on this site see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A3382+transfer+function